# Can't get bound value when setting DataContext in Loaded event

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a user control that shows a bindable text. If I put this user control in a window and set the DataContext in Loaded event of that window, I can't retrieve the text in the Loaded event of the control. Why?

If I set the DataContext in MainWindow constructor everything works.

So is it wrong to set the DataContext in Loaded event?

Here is my sample code:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlBinding.TestControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         x:Name="thisControl"
         Loaded="OnLoaded"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextToShow, ElementName=thisControl}" />
</Grid>
```

```
    public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public string TextToShow
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextToShowProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextToShowProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextToShowProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextToShow", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TestControl.OnLoaded: DataContext=" + DataContext);
        Debug.WriteLine("TestControl.OnLoaded: TextToShow=" + TextToShow);
    }
}


<Window x:Class="UserControlBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlBinding"
    Loaded="OnLoaded"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:TestControl TextToShow="{Binding TextToBind}" />
</Grid>
```

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string TextToBind
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextToBindProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextToBindProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextToBindProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TextToBind", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //this.DataContext = this;  // if I do this it works
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("+MainWindow.OnLoaded");
        TextToBind = "this is the text to bind";
        this.DataContext = this;
        Debug.WriteLine("-MainWindow.OnLoaded");
    }
}
```

Debug output is:

```
+MainWindow.OnLoaded
-MainWindow.OnLoaded
TestControl.OnLoaded: DataContext=UserControlBinding.MainWindow
TestControl.OnLoaded: TextToShow=
```

Comment: Whats the point in this.DataContext = this;  in Main Windows?

Comment: It's just a sample, in real program it is a view model

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you just **can't rely on the bindings being completed** when the `Loaded` event fires.

If you attach a `PropertyChangedCallback` to your TextToShow property you can see that it's fired after the `Loaded` event of `TestControl` when you set the DataContext in the `Loaded` event of your `MainWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

Its not required to set the `DataContext` here, rather than you could go for `Binding` with `RelativeSource`..

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TextToShow, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />

<local:TestControl TextToShow="{Binding TextToBind, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Comment: RelativeSource Self gives me BindingExpression path error: 'TextToBind' property not found on 'object' ''TestControl'.
And anyway this wouldn't help if I used a seperate view model.

Comment: `<local:TestControl TextToShow="{Binding TextToBind, RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />` - you can this also.. and more over it will not be a problem if you used a seperate viewModel, coz `TextToBind` is in your `TestControl` which is a `UserControl` will not be affected due to the ViewModel...